# Join or create new farm? SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, server-farm

I have a SharePoint 2013 server where the installation is corrupted. I have two sites, one of which works and the other one doesn't. I am able to access some areas of Central administration but not all. For example if I try to view Site Collections it says the page cannot load due to corruption.

I have built a new SharePoint 2013 server and I am wondering whether I should create a new farm and detach/attach the databases or whether I should join this new server to the existing farm and make the new server host the central admin site instead? - with my theory being that there would no longer be any corruption at least not on this server. Then once that done, move the site to the new server   instead of using the old.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would join the new server to the farm with option to host the central admin on new server. this way i will avoid the migration if I create a new farm, in new farm i have to create and configure everything which is configured on existing farm. couple of things to keep in mind.

- make sure your new server should have the same version / build level as the exiting one
- start all the services on the new server
- If you have any custom configuration then make the same change on the new server.
- if that server is also your WFE and you are using the DNS then update your DNS record.
- test the new server
- Now remove the corrupt server from the farm ( before removing, make sure you stop all services on that server.)

Answer (score 0):

create new farm and attach only content databases, this is the best and clear (maybe fastes too) solution.

Comment: OK, do I need to create the web applications first and then the site collections prior to attaching the content databases?

Comment: Yes, create web applications and attach the existing databases to them

Comment: So I have a bigger issue now. I cannot attach the database to the new farm as the schema version is different. As the original server is corrupted I cannot do anything on there all I know is that it is pre-SP1 and the PSConfig tool cannot upgrade the server to SP1 following SP1 patchbeing installed.I am at a loss on how to get this database to attach now to the new server which I've now tried with SP1 and same version as old server but new server cannot upgrade either.

Comment: which commandlet do you use?